# I want to make a hotword for my JARVIS AI

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, hotword

I wanted to ask if there if a way to make a hotword for my JARVIS AI made in python 3.7.6(windows 7). I want that JARVIS become activated whenever I say "Hey Jarvis"(just like Hey siri). the code of my jarvis is given below. I have tried the library named lshotword but it gave an error named no module named tensorflow

```
import pyttsx3

import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
# Use female voice
import pyperclip
hiddenimports = [
   'pyttsx3.drivers',
   'pyttsx3.drivers.dummy',
   'pyttsx3.drivers.espeak',
   'pyttsx3.drivers.nsss',
   'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5', ]

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices = engine.getProperty('voice')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices)
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
engine.setProperty('volume', 10)

def speak(audio):
 engine.say(audio)
 engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
   hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
   if hour>=0 and hour<12:
       speak("Good Morning!")
   elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
       speak("Good Afternoon!")
   else:
       speak("Good Evening!")
   speak("I am friday, is there anything to help you sir?")

def takecommand():
   r = sr.Recognizer()
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       print("Listening....")
       r.pause_threshold = 1
       audio = r.listen(source)
   try:
    print("Recognizing....")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
    print(f"user said: {query}\n")
   except Exception as e:
     print(e)
     return "None"
   return query


def typenh():
   r = sr.Recognizer()
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       print("Listening....")
       r.pause_threshold = 1
       audio = r.listen(source)
   try:
    print("Recognizing....")
    typethingh = r.recognize_google(audio, language='hi')
    print(f"user said: {typethingh}\n")
   except Exception as e:
     print(e)
     speak("sorry I could not understand, say that again please...")
     return "None"
   return typethingh



if __name__ == "__main__": 
   wishMe()
   while True:
    query = takecommand().lower()
    query.replace("could you", "")
    query.replace("please", "")
    if 'wikipedia' in query:
           speak('searching Wikipedia...')
           query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
           results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
           speak("according to wikipedia")
           speak(results)
    if 'manav sampada' in query:
           speak('loging in to manav sampada')
           browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromedriver.exe')
           browser.get('http://ehrms.upsdc.gov.in/')
           elem = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('eHRMS Login')
           elem.get_attribute('href')
           time.sleep(1)
           elem.click()
           time.sleep(1)
           loginr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtusername"]')
           loginr.send_keys('your id ')
           time.sleep(1)
           select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ddldept'))
           select.select_by_visible_text('Basic Education')
           time.sleep(1)
           password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtpwd"]')
           password.send_keys('your password')
           speak('sir I have filled all userID password etc. but ')
           speak('sir you have to fill the human verification captha by yourself as I am just a bot ')
           speak('I hope I was able to assist you')
    if 'software' in query:
           speak('opening sir')
           query = query.replace("software", "")
           pyautogui.click(27, 880)
           pyautogui.typewrite(query)
           time.sleep(1)
           pyautogui.click(79,441)
    if 'send' and 'gmail' in query:
           speak('opening gmail')
           browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromedriver.exe')
           browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/b/0/AddMailService')
           time.sleep(1)
           login = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
           login.send_keys('your gmail id @gmail.com')
           login.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
           time.sleep(1)
           loginpwd = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
           loginpwd.send_keys('your awesom password here')
           loginpwd.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
           time.sleep(10)
           try:
               speak('just a sec')
               compose = browser.find_element_by_class_name('z0')
               time.sleep(2)
               compose.click()
               time.sleep(1)
               speak('whom do you want to send the gmail')
               sendto = takecommand().lower()
               sendto = ''.join(sendto.split())
               tom = browser.find_element_by_name('to')
               tom.send_keys(sendto)
               speak('what is the subject?')
               subject = browser.find_element_by_name('subjectbox')
               time.sleep(0.5)
               
               whatissu = takecommand()
               subject.send_keys(whatissu)
               body = browser.find_element_by_name('Message Body')
               speak('what is the main body?')
               mainbody = takecommand()
               body.send_keys(mainbody)

           except Exception as identifier:
               compose = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":jm"]/div/div')
               time.sleep(1)
               compose.click()
               time.sleep(1)
               speak('whom do you want to send the gmail')
               sendto = takecommand().lower()
               sendto = ''.join(sendto.split())
               tom = browser.find_element_by_name('to')
               tom.send_keys(sendto)                                                   
               subject = browser.find_element_by_name('subjectbox')
               time.sleep(0.5)
               speak('what is the subject?')
               whatissu = takecommand()
               subject.send_keys(whatissu)
               body = browser.find_element_by_name('Message Body')
               speak('what is the main body?')
               mainbody = takecommand()
               body.send_keys(mainbody)            
       
    if 'hindi' in query:
       speak('what to type?')
       typethingh = typenh()
       content = typethingh
       pyperclip.copy(content)
       time.sleep(0.5)
       pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')

    if 'do you have a boyfriend' in query:
        speak('I am happy to be single')

    if 'siri' in query:
        speak('siri is smart but I dont like him')

    if 'how are you' in query:
        speak('I am good ')

    if 'i hate you' in query:
        speak('than go to siri or google. why are you even talking to me')

    if 'who is your creator' in query:
        speak("my creater is aditya maurya")

    if 'who made you' in query:
        speak('aditya maurya made me. he is also known as estriadi')

    if 'who created you' in query:
        speak('aditya maurya created me    ')

    if 'whatsapp' in query:
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromedriver.exe')
        speak('opening whatsapp web')
        browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
        speak('please scan the qr code. I am waiting for 10 seconds')
        time.sleep(10)
        try:
            find = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="side"]/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]')
            find.click()
            speak('tell the first word of the contact to whom you want to send the messege')
            sendmsg = takecommand()
            find.send_keys(sendmsg)
            time.sleep(1.5)
            find.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            try:
                typenum = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
                typenum.click()
                speak('what do you want to send sir?')
                whattosend = takecommand()
                typenum.send_keys(whattosend)
                typenum.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            except Exception as identifier:
                speak('there is no contact as'+sendmsg)
        except Exception as identifier:
            speak('you did not make it in 10 seconds')


    if 'quit' in query:
       exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to listen right at the beginning for Hey Jarvis, and if you hear that, you execute the rest of the code.

Here is how I did it:

```python
import pyttsx3

import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
# Use female voice
import pyperclip
hiddenimports = [
   'pyttsx3.drivers',
   'pyttsx3.drivers.dummy',
   'pyttsx3.drivers.espeak',
   'pyttsx3.drivers.nsss',
   'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5', ]

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices = engine.getProperty('voice')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices)
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
engine.setProperty('volume', 10)

def speak(audio):
 engine.say(audio)
 engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
   hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
   if hour>=0 and hour<12:
       speak("Good Morning!")
   elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
       speak("Good Afternoon!")
   else:
       speak("Good Evening!")
   speak("I am friday, is there anything to help you sir?")

def takecommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening....")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing....")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return "None"
    return query


def typenh():
   r = sr.Recognizer()
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       print("Listening....")
       r.pause_threshold = 1
       audio = r.listen(source)
   try:
    print("Recognizing....")
    typethingh = r.recognize_google(audio, language='hi')
    print(f"user said: {typethingh}\n")
   except Exception as e:
     print(e)
     speak("sorry I could not understand, say that again please...")
     return "None"
   return typethingh

i = 0

#Edited From Here
n = 0
k = 0

print("Say Hey Jarvis To Begin Initiation Sequence") #Sounds SICK Right!
while (i<1):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        n=(n+1)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        # interprete audio (Google Speech Recognition)
    try:
        s = (r.recognize_google(audio))
        message = (s.lower())

        if message == "hey jarvis":
            wishMe()
            k = 0
            while k == 0:
                query = takecommand().lower()
                query.replace("could you", "")
                query.replace("please", "")

                if 'sleep' in query:
                    speak("Entering Sleep Mode. Say Hey Jarvis To Wake Me Up!")
                    k = 1
                    print("Say Hey Jarvis To Begin Initiation Sequence")
                    #Editing Ends Here
                if 'wikipedia' in query:
                       speak('searching Wikipedia...')
                       query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
                       results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
                       speak("according to wikipedia")
                       speak(results)
                if 'manav sampada' in query:
                       speak('loging in to manav sampada')
                       browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromedriver.exe')
                       browser.get('http://ehrms.upsdc.gov.in/')
                       elem = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('eHRMS Login')
                       elem.get_attribute('href')
                       time.sleep(1)
                       elem.click()
                       time.sleep(1)
                       loginr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtusername"]')
                       loginr.send_keys('your id ')
                       time.sleep(1)
                       select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ddldept'))
                       select.select_by_visible_text('Basic Education')
                       time.sleep(1)
                       password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtpwd"]')
                       password.send_keys('your password')
                       speak('sir I have filled all userID password etc. but ')
                       speak('sir you have to fill the human verification captha by yourself as I am just a bot ')
                       speak('I hope I was able to assist you')
                if 'software' in query:
                       speak('opening sir')
                       query = query.replace("software", "")
                       pyautogui.click(27, 880)
                       pyautogui.typewrite(query)
                       time.sleep(1)
                       pyautogui.click(79,441)
                if 'send' and 'gmail' in query:
                       speak('opening gmail')
                       browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromedriver.exe')
                       browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/b/0/AddMailService')
                       time.sleep(1)
                       login = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
                       login.send_keys('your gmail id @gmail.com')
                       login.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                       time.sleep(1)
                       loginpwd = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
                       loginpwd.send_keys('your awesom password here')
                       loginpwd.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                       time.sleep(10)
                       try:
                           speak('just a sec')
                           compose = browser.find_element_by_class_name('z0')
                           time.sleep(2)
                           compose.click()
                           time.sleep(1)
                           speak('whom do you want to send the gmail')
                           sendto = takecommand().lower()
                           sendto = ''.join(sendto.split())
                           tom = browser.find_element_by_name('to')
                           tom.send_keys(sendto)
                           speak('what is the subject?')
                           subject = browser.find_element_by_name('subjectbox')
                           time.sleep(0.5)
                           
                           whatissu = takecommand()
                           subject.send_keys(whatissu)
                           body = browser.find_element_by_name('Message Body')
                           speak('what is the main body?')
                           mainbody = takecommand()
                           body.send_keys(mainbody)

                       except Exception as identifier:
                           compose = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":jm"]/div/div')
                           time.sleep(1)
                           compose.click()
                           time.sleep(1)
                           speak('whom do you want to send the gmail')
                           sendto = takecommand().lower()
                           sendto = ''.join(sendto.split())
                           tom = browser.find_element_by_name('to')
                           tom.send_keys(sendto)                                                   
                           subject = browser.find_element_by_name('subjectbox')
                           time.sleep(0.5)
                           speak('what is the subject?')
                           whatissu = takecommand()
                           subject.send_keys(whatissu)
                           body = browser.find_element_by_name('Message Body')
                           speak('what is the main body?')
                           mainbody = takecommand()
                           body.send_keys(mainbody)            
                   
                if 'hindi' in query:
                   speak('what to type?')
                   typethingh = typenh()
                   content = typethingh
                   pyperclip.copy(content)
                   time.sleep(0.5)
                   pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')

                if 'do you have a boyfriend' in query:
                    speak('I am happy to be single')

                if 'siri' in query:
                    speak('siri is smart but I dont like him')

                if 'how are you' in query:
                    speak('I am good ')

                if 'i hate you' in query:
                    speak('than go to siri or google. why are you even talking to me')

                if 'who is your creator' in query:
                    speak("my creater is John Cena(The OG Himself)")

                if 'who made you' in query:
                    speak('John Cena Made e. He Is An OG!')

                if 'who created you' in query:
                    speak('Booooob The BUILDER!!!')

                if 'whatsapp' in query:
                    browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\chromedriver.exe')
                    speak('opening whatsapp web')
                    browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
                    speak('please scan the qr code. I am waiting for 10 seconds')
                    time.sleep(10)
                    try:
                        find = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="side"]/div[1]/div/label/div/div[2]')
                        find.click()
                        speak('tell the first word of the contact to whom you want to send the messege')
                        sendmsg = takecommand()
                        find.send_keys(sendmsg)
                        time.sleep(1.5)
                        find.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                        try:
                            typenum = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
                            typenum.click()
                            speak('what do you want to send sir?')
                            whattosend = takecommand()
                            typenum.send_keys(whattosend)
                            typenum.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                        except Exception as identifier:
                            speak('there is no contact as'+sendmsg)
                    except Exception as identifier:
                        speak('you did not make it in 10 seconds')


                if 'quit' in query:
                   exit()

    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Let me explain:

At line 76, I define 2 more variables which we will need later: n and k.
At line 79, I print a message telling the user to say 'Hey Jarvis' to start the AI.
At line 80, I start a while loop. This loop listens for Hey Jarvis and Hey Jarvis ONLY!

The while loop is very similar to your function called takecommand(), so I won't explain.

At line 91, it checks to see if the query/message is EQUAL to ONLY 'Hey Jarvis'. If it is, then it starts the execution of your code.

The final edit I made was to return the AI to sleep mode where it would sleep and once again wait for the user to say 'Hey Jarvis'.

If 'sleep' is said to the AI, then it tells the user that it will be entering sleep mode. Then, it changes k to equal to 1. This breaks the while loop because the while loop works AS LONG as k == 0.

Comment: thanks it worked ! but if the jarvis is recognizing and at that time if I say 'hey jarvis' then he don't listen to me as It is recognizing.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. You could try to find a way to make jarvis strart listening when he hears a sound.

Comment: Ok starting to research on that. thanks !